# How to sign in to Android Studio with Google Account?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make ads work and I can't find how can I sign-in with Google account. What I find is [integration](http://google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02ga2iXd-n-C1TmWsdQU8W-n5eKUQ%3A1582411938986&ei=orBRXrfwO-6Uk74PtPW28Ak&q=sign%20in%20google%20android%20studio&oq=sign%20in%20google%20android%20studio&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30j0i8i7i30l9.8501.9574..9680...0.2..0.184.936.0j6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i5i30.haR-JwuZ0ng&ved=0ahUKEwi3yYvsn-bnAhVuysQBHbS6DZ4Q4dUDCAs&uact=5) of signing-in in app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the little profile picture icon in the top right:

[image: profile picture icon]

Comment: What are the benefits of logging in?

1- You can view crashlytics reports within the IDE

What else?

Answer (score 5):

***Android Studio Login***

Find this icon in the top right corner of Android Studio. Then click and complete registration by google account.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using icon in the top right corner of Android Studio You Can Complete Your SignIn.